# CromisIPC compilation error on DELPHI 7

Tags: delphi, ipc

I get the CromisIPC [cromis ipc site download](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/cromis-ipc/) and compile/rum successfully the demos and custom project on delphi XE5. Without any error.

But, when I get the same code and put on DELPHI 7 project, I have an error on unit Cromis. AnyValue, an compilation error.

```
  TAnyValue = packed record
  private
    ValueData: TValueDataType;
    {$IFDEF AnyValue_HookingOff}
      IntfData : IInterface;
    {$ELSE}
      {$IFNDEF CPUX64}
        Padding : array [0..3] of Byte;
      {$ENDIF}
    {$ENDIF}
    ValueType: TValueType;
    function GetAsInt64: Int64; inline;
```

Exactly on lyne:

> ```
>   ValueData: TValueDataType;
> ```

```
[Error] Cromis.AnyValue.pas(210): ',' or ':' expected but identifier 'ValueData' found

[Error] Cromis.AnyValue.pas(219): 'END' expected but 'FUNCTION' found
```

I use `delphi 7` on a 64 bits windows 7 with a 32 bits VCL project.

The same code compiles on XE5.

What happens here ? any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** This code is not designed to work under Delphi 7.

---

Visibility specifiers are not allowed in Delphi 7 records. The compiler is objecting to the use of `private`. You can remove that, but then the next problem will be all the methods that are declared on the record. Again, they are not available in Delphi 7.

You might be able to make some headway by switching from `packed record` to `packed object`. However, I think it highly unlikely that this will be smooth sailing. Expect a lot of work to make this code compile on Delphi 7. Frankly, you would need to be a Delphi expert to take on this task.

You might try to find an old version of the library that actually supports Delphi 7. You might be able to get one from the library's author. But note that the [website](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/) says:

> All code is Delphi 2006 and upwards compatible. I will not support older Delphi version. If you still use them, then its time to upgrade.

Which leads to the other obvious solution. Upgrade to a modern version of Delphi.

If that is impossible, then you should look for a different library.